# Determine whether this series is convergent or divergent. (sins in series)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine where the series:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\sin^4(n)}{n^2+1}$$

Would the comparison test not work? Since there is a $\sin^4$ I would not be able to take its dx easily, would there be a better theorem to use?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** prove that the series is absolutely convergent. You can use the comparison for that.

Comment: NB the sequece is strictly positive, so $\sum a_n = \sum |a_n|$...

Comment: What do you see in this series that sparks your interest to prove that it is absolutely convergent?

Comment: So I got to this: I set my $a_N$ to the sequence, and used the ratio test. I got to the last part and determined that lim as n goes to infinity of (1/(n+1)) is less than one, meaning the sum is absolutely convergent. Does that sound ideal?

Answer (score 1):

$$
-1\le \sin n\le 1
$$
Therefore $0\le\sin^4 n\le 1$. And therefore
$$
\left|\frac{\sin^4(n)}{n^2+1}\right| \le \frac 1 {n^2+1} \le \frac 1 {n^2}
$$

So think about $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^2}$.